# Issue Getting correct Full Path in Unit Testing

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, unit-testing, asp.net-core

Having an issue in getting the correct path to a file during unit testing, the file exist in "C:\Users\Name\source\repos\ProjectOne\ProjectOneTests\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\Test\textFile.txt"

```
 string fileName = "textFile.txt";
 string directoryName = Path.GetFullPath(fileName);
```

directoryName =**"C:\Users\Name\source\repos\ProjectOne\ProjectOneTests\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1"**

directoryName should be **"C:\Users\Name\source\repos\ProjectOne\ProjectOneTests\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\Test"**

If I write code

```
 string fileName = "Test\\textFile.txt";
 string directoryName = Path.GetFullPath(fileName);
```

Then directoryName =**"C:\Users\Name\source\repos\ProjectOne\ProjectOneTests\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\Test"**

Why is Path.GetFullPath giving me the incorrect path when I only call file name **"textFile.txt"**
I can't seem to find any sources on stack or google to explain why and how I can get the correct path inside netcoreapp3.1 path, any advice, sources or help would be appreciated

Comment: `Path.GetFullPath` just adds fileName to `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()`

Comment: Could you please share some more about your test cases so that It will help us to reproduce your issue.

Comment: Thanks so much @FireAlkazar I did that and it worked. I appreciate your help.

Comment: Also I'm sorry for the delay especially to @md-farid-uddin-kiron I resolved the issues. Thanks so much!